# Which user is displayed as the editor of an answer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A few days ago I edited someone else's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172633/1020530).

Then it went for review. Today when I looked at the answer I saw that my edit was added, but someone else is displayed as being the editor.

Who should be displayed as the editor of the answer, the one who edited it or the one who reviewed it?

Comment: Note that I edited your question (nothing really to fix, but to prove the point). Somebody reviewed the edition and accepted it, and I appear as editor.

Comment: @dystroy, I think that your answer was good, and I don't really care about the credit. Stackoverflow is one of my bests friends, since it helped me so many times. I want to give back to the community as I got from her. The only problem that I have is that since my reputation is low, there are too many things that I can't do. My number 1 problem is that I cannot commit anywhere. And also I just was curious.
By the way, your editing of my question didn't prove your point, it proved mine, Bart is the one that written as the editor. But as you said he probably edited your edit.

Comment: There is no "editor", there are just edits. The last one to edit will have his/her name on the post together with a time stamp, nothing more.

Comment: During half an hour, before Bart came to edit again (without reading the comment, I assume), I was marked as author of the last edit ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the one who edited it. But sometimes you edit an answer and the reviewer fixes something in your edit, making him the "author" of the new version of the edit. Or somebody's else, later, does it, even outside the reviewing process.

SO is a collaborative site, don't pay too much attention to the authorship of edits.

In the specific case you link to, you made the error to comment too much your edit (*"I think that this edit need to be as comment, but I could not comment on this answer so I edited it."*). There is a field to explain to reviewers why you edit, avoid being too verbose or personal in your edits, just focus on making the answer better if you can, without changing it too much. And don't try to make it yours, or to leave a visible mark.